# How to bring another project (get,post) api method to swagger api project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I've created one API project with asp.net core in which I used **swashbuckle.AspNetCore.dll** to generate swagger.

It is working perfectly and going well.

Now I have another C#(.NET Standard library) in which I have created some GET, POST, DELETE, PUT method.

Need to load all of those methods to the swagger API project.

I've tried to use that separate C# library(*.dll*) to my project, but it didn't load to swagger.

Added this line to configuration service method at Startup.cs file:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme {
                In = "header", Description = "Please enter JWT with Bearer into field",
                Name = "Authorization", Type = "apiKey"
        });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> {
        { "Bearer", Enumerable.Empty<string>() },
    });
});
```

Added this line to Configure method at startup.cs file:

```
app.UseSwagger();

// Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), 
// specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```

It shows swagger with swagger project method. It should show both methods whether it is in a separate library or swagger project itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing Swagger UI for API in a different project (Swashbuckle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601034/showing-swagger-ui-for-api-in-a-different-project-swashbuckle)

Comment: @ManojChoudhari nope this is not a duplicate... The challenge on this case is that one project is asp.net core and the other is .net standard

Comment: @sk5202 Can you create/add a sample project reproducing this on Github?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda yes sure will inform you once done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used service stack swagger instead of swashbuckle.

It's solve my problem.

here is the solution.

https://forums.servicestack.net/t/guidance-on-enabling-oauth-2-0-in-generated-swagger-docs/3995/18

Comment: A $1,000 library isn't exactly a viable solution for most people